# Syntax highlighting doesn't activate without language tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The [syntax highlighter has changed on all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting): now it is only enabled if the question contains specific tags (mostly language or framework related). Since all questions on this site are about WordPress, we don't use the [wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) or [php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) tags, and none of the new questions get syntax highlighting.

I think the WP SE should have the default syntax highlighter (without language hint) enabled, since it seemed to work pretty good for our needs (PHP, HTML, JS, CSS, occasionally SQL). Otherwise we would need to add almost every tag to the syntax highlighter.

I'm tagging this question [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in the hope that it gets noticed by one of the overlords...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE:

**Wordpress will now style by default when there are no tags that match other language hints.**

[wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) is set to the default language hint and [php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) is set to php.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that we don't use those tags, as every question is about WordPress and almost every question uses PHP. Just like you don't use `programming-question` on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jan what percent of questions have PHP code?

Comment: @Jeff: Of the 50 questions on the home page, 27 contain code, and 23 of these contain PHP code. https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Aj28CyxNAlPvdEw1eHE1c2U2Z0ZQYkhwSkFpTW1jWUE&hl=en

Comment: @jan ok we will look into this. This site is a bit unique in that regard

Answer (score 1):

Jan, excellent point, thanks for catching this. I [posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting/72437#72437) on that SO meta thread to point this out - I suggest that you (and whoever else thinks this is important) vote my answer up so as to get the attention of the necessary people.

Comment: Great! Geoff reverted the `[status-completed]` tag, so at least they know we have a problem here!

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree and i noticed highlighting still works the old way in the preview box though.

+1000000 from me.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can't there be a default fallback to PHP if not further language has been specified? I think that catches most of the cases.

> **UPDATE: [This is how it is now](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294/syntax-highlighting-doesnt-activate-without-language-tag/297#297).**

Comment: I don't think we need to specify the language: this would prevent correct highlighting of Javascript if that tag is not used. The default settings works for most languages, but not so good for SQL, VB, Lisp, ... which is why this new system makes sense for Stack Overflow, but not for WPSE.